# Size of connected regions on a randomly-colored infinite chessboard

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-geometry, random-graphs, clustering, percolation

Consider an infinite chessboard where each square is colored white with probability $p$ and black with probability $1-p$. Suppose without loss of generality that the square at $(0,0)$ is white.  We can consider the entire connected region $W$ of white squares that includes the white square at $(0,0)$; that is, the set of all squares that are reachable from $(0,0)$ via an all-white path of adjacent squares. (Squares are deemed to be adjacent if they share an edge.) The expected size $E_W$ of $W$ is a monotonically-increasing function of $p$ with minimum value 1.

> At what value of $p$ does $E_W$ become infinite?  (That is, what is $\inf \{p : E_W(p) = \infty \}?)$

(Clearly there is such a value, since for $p$ close to 1, nearly all the squares are white, and nearly all of them are reachable from $(0,0)$.)

I would especially like a reference to a monograph on this topic and topics related to it. (What if the chessboard is partitioned into more than 2 pieces?  What if it is replaced with some other graph? What is the probability $p_\infty$ that region $W$ is infinite, as a function of $p$?  At what value of $p$ does $p_\infty$  become positive?  If $r_p(s)$ is the probability that the region containing $(0,0)$ has size exactly $s$ squares when squares are white with probability $p$, just how is $r_p$ distributed?) Is Roach *The theory of random clumping* (Methuen, 1968) what I am looking for?

(Please retag this question as appropriate.)

Comment: You're aware of [percolation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory)? "By Kolmogorov's zero-one law, for any given $p$, the probability that an infinite cluster exists is either zero or one." The critical threshold [appears to be about $0.592746$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_threshold) for the square lattice. But I don't know if it makes a difference to require that the infinite cluster contains the origin.

Comment: I wasn't, thanks! This will at least give me something to follow up.

Comment: Possibly useful:[A mini course on percolation theory](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~steif/perc.pdf) by Steif.

Comment: @RahulNarain The critical threshold for the square lattice is 1/2. There is no difference in requiring that the origin belongs to the infinite region.

Comment: @MJD The standard reference is Grimmett (it is ref. [12] in the mini course). There is also book Percolation by Bolobas and Riordan, from 2006 (if I am not mistaken).

Comment: @Artem: My knowledge is limited to the Wikipedia articles I linked to, but according to them the critical thresholds for bond percolation ($p_c=1/2$) and site percolation ($p_c\approx0.593$) are different. I believe the question asks about site percolation.

Comment: @RahulNarain Yes, indeed, my comment above is wrong.

Comment: Is the board infinite in all directions?

Comment: Yes, or I would have said “quarter-infinite”. Those Stief notes on percolation theory I linked above are very interesting, although I can only find discussion of the very similar problem where the *edges* between the chessboard squares are either walls (disconnecting the two squares on either side) or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As rightly mentioned in the comments, the needed keyword is "site percolation on square lattice". The expected size of a cluster containing the origin indeed jumps from 0 to infinity when $p$ passes the site percolation theshold for this lattice, $p_c$. In the vicinity of $p=p_c$, $p_\infty=0$ at $p<p_c$, and otherwise $p_\infty\propto(p-p_c)^\beta$ where $\beta=5/36$ is called a critical exponent. For more information about clusters on percolating lattices and critical exponents in percolation theory, including cluster number distribution, check out [the lecture notes by Christensen](http://www.mit.edu/~levitov/8.334/notes/percol_notes.pdf).