# Expected size of colored block on chessboard?

Tags: probability, expected-value, chessboard, percolation

Randomly color the squares of an $m\times n$ chessboard red or black (each square has a fifty-fifty chance of being red or black). A monochromatic region is a set of squares that are connected along their sides and all of the same color, that is, for any $2$ squares in the region there is a path connecting the $2$ that stays on the same color.

What is the expected size of a monochromatic region, given $m,n$?

Comment: Linked to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570860/size-of-connected-regions-on-a-randomly-colored-infinite-chessboard The keyword is *percolation*

Comment: The expected size of the **smallest** monochromatic region, or the expected size of the **largest** monochromatic region, or the expected size of the **average** monochromatic region???

Comment: Average monchromatic region