# Connected spatial regions assigned to random colours: How large are connected regions of one colour likely to be?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry

I have been trying to calculate a value that has come up for me in a geography field, which I feel may be an elementary solved problem in combinatorics or a graph theory (or on the flip side, known to be very difficult). I have some maths background (undergraduate degree) but hardly anything in discrete maths, so I have no intuition here.

My problem is to do with connected geographic areas that have been randomly assigned to a certain colour. Ideally, I want to know the expected distribution of the sizes of connected regions of the same colour. It occured to me that the geographic regions and their neighbours could be considered as a graph, like this (I've shown the sizes of the connected areas, the distribution of which I am interested in):

[image]

I'm not sure how to formulate this as a graph theory problem, but it could be something like:

Given a connected graph of size m, partitioned into k (not likely to be connected) subgraphs by assigning points at random, what is the expected size of the connected sub-subgraphs of each of the k subgraphs.

I do not need an exact answer (though of course that would be very helpful) but some guidance on how to consider this problem and whether or not it is a 'standard' or 'solved' problem in graph theory would be amazing. It seems from [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570860/size-of-connected-regions-on-a-randomly-colored-infinite-chessboard) that percolation theory might help me here (in the sense that considering the red graph, the blue nodes have been removed). I'm not certain though because I'm not interested in whether there is an open path (in my case the answer will always be no).

Comment: Percolation theory *also* deals with the study of expected cluster sizes. Note, though, that its exact value on a finite graph will depend heavily on the particular graph structure. In other words: If you want the exact answer, there's probably not much to do except write down all the possible clusters of all the possible vertices and brute forcing the problem that way.

Comment: Damn, that would be tricky. Do you think there's a chance of approximations/ranges based on some simplifying assumptions like every vertex has n connections or something like that?

Comment: There aren't even explicit formulae on Z^2 (all we know is the standard spiel of exponential decay of cluster sizes below the critical probability and exponential decay of dual cluster sizes above it and some bounds on critical exponents for near-critical analysis).
 What *would* probably be simplifying matters greatly is if your graph is easily disconnected. For instance, in your graph above, you never have to consider the bottom two vertices since if their clusters are large, then the clusters of their respective neighbours must also be large.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it can't be easily disconnected. What is Z^2?

Comment: The square lattice.

Comment: oh that doesn't bode well